# PowerShell 3.0 Installation Error on Windows 7 SP1

Tags: powershell

I have been trying for a couple days to get Windows Management Framework 3.0 to install on my Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1 desktop machine. The installation seems to go fine, and at the end it requests a reboot as it should. After the reboot, it says installation has failed and rolls everything back out.

In the System Setup Logs it shows the following error:
Package KB2506143 failed to be changed to the Installed state. Status: 0x80070005.

I definitely meet the pre-requisites. I have uninstalled .NET 4.5 and 4.0 and re-installed both, with reboots in between. It always comes back with that same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try following the steps mentioned here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/unable-to-install-update-for-kb2506143-with-error/27bf0b6e-a7e1-483f-908d-487d1c9d564d

Comment: I have tried those but to no avail. I think I might have found where my problem lies, but have not had any success in locating a fix. The following is from c:\windows\logs\cbs\cbs.log. Looks like it's having a hard time with a file operation.

Comment: 2013-11-15 12:19:58, Error                 CSI    00000006 (F) Error: ResolvePendingTransactions called after poqexec failure (call 1)
  Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, Operation = HardLinkFile, DiagString = [l:416{208}]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-p..ll-preloc.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_7.1.7601.16398_en-us_10f668d0433100eb\default.help.txt, \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US\default.help.txt"
[gle=0x80004005]
2013-11-15 12:19:59, Error

Comment: 2013-11-15 12:19:59, Error                 CBS    Startup: Primitive operations failed, startupPhase: 0.  The transaction will be cancelled. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]

Comment: I have also run the System Update Readiness Tool prior to my installation and it came back clean. I'm stuck at the moment. If I ever do get this resolved I'll be sure to post the final resolution. This is a fun one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the installation as Administrator. It's not sufficient to be logged on with an account that has local admin privileges; you need to select **Run as administrator** from the context menu, or run it from an elevated command prompt. I ran into that error the first time I tried to install Management Framework 3.0 by just double-clicking the downloaded .exe file. It worked when I launched it from an elevated prompt (**Run as administrator** would have the same effect).

Comment: I had tried that, but tried it one more time. This did not resolve my issue. 

In my WindowsUpdate.log I found the following: wusa Failure Content Install Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80070005: Update for Windows (KB2506143).

I also had my domain admin remove me from the group policy and that did not fix my install issue. From what I understand, 0x80070005 is a permissions problem, but I'm at a loss as it doesn't really tell me where.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the .Net Framework WoW64 features were missing.  More specifically mscoree.dll couldn't be found.  Installing the NetFx2-ServerCore-WoW64 & NetFx3-ServerCore-WoW64 features fixed the problem for me.

http://josheinstein.com/blog/2011/09/solved-this-program-cant-start-because-mscoree-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer/